# jQuery trigger a DatePicker change event

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui

I have the following code:

```
$('.custom_datepicker_selector').datepicker({
  weekStart: 1
})
.on('changeDate', function(en) {
  var correct_format;
  correct_format = en.date.getFullYear() + '-' + ('0' + (en.date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' + ('0' + en.date.getDate()).slice(-2);
  $('.custom_datepicker_selector').datepicker('hide');
  return $(this).parent().find("input[type=hidden]").val(correct_format);
});
```

This displays the date format just like I want it to.  However it only does so after I click on the datepicker, not initially.

Initially this date is shown:

```
2013-02-17
```

and after I click on it I get this:

```
17/02/2013
```

How can I display the correct date immediately?  (the code above is in the .ready

I created a jsFiddle for this:
http://jsfiddle.net/jwxvz/

This was more a rails problem than a javascript:

I followed abu advice and did it like this in rails:

```
<%= f.input :order_date, :as => :custom_datepicker, :input_html =>  { :value => localize(@client_order.order_date) } %>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define the default date format also.

Try this out:

```
$('.custom_datepicker_selector').datepicker({
  weekStart: 1,
  dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
}).on('changeDate', function(en) {
      $('.custom_datepicker_selector').datepicker('hide');
      return $(this).parent().find("input[type=hidden]").val(en);
   });
```

**UPDATE : (important)**

I have seen your JSFiddle, you have kept the default value of the textbox as `value="2013-02-17"` that's why it shows that value at start just remove it.

Comment: That value is coming from Rails. I want the datepicker to do the formatting, isn't that possible?

Comment: If that value is coming from rails than you have to do the formatting

Answer (score 0):

just you have to use:

```
$('.custom_datepicker_selector').datepicker({
weekStart: 1,
dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd'
})
```

you can reference here : [link](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-formats)