# How to get the value of date picker on change in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I need to get the value of date onchange ,

Here is the code

```
<div class="input-daterange" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy">

       <label>Date </label>                                                       
<input id="value_date"  class="form-control"  name="start" type="text" />                                                                              
</div>
```

Here is my jquery

```
$('#value_date').change(function() {{

    var valuefirstone = document.getElementById('#value_date').value;
    alert(valuefirstone);
}
</script>
```

Onchange the function is not calling, I have just create alert on change but its not working

Comment: remove your "#" on your getElementById

Comment: use simple $('#value_date').val();

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery trigger a DatePicker change event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14919563/jquery-trigger-a-datepicker-change-event)

Comment: why dont you use $(this).val() ?

Comment: the function is not calling onchange

Comment: because your function syntax is wrong

Comment: @NishadKAhamed the function not even working , even after changing

Comment: make sure you put this function inside $(document).ready() fn

Comment: remove one flower brace in this line 1 `$('#value_date').change(function() {{`

Answer (score 0):

try this ;

```
$('#value_date').datepicker().on('changeDate', function (ev) {
    var valuefirstone = $(this).val();
    alert(valuefirstone);
});
```

Remove the `.datepicker()` if it's done earlier

Comment: Are you using bootstrap datepicker? are you sure it's correctly load on your page?

Comment: Yes i am using bootstrap date picker , Its loaded

Answer (score 0):

it is better to use `jquery` built in functions inside a `jquery context`. Also your `jquery change function` syntax and `javascript` code to get the value from date picker is wrong.

change your jquery change function to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#value_date').change(function() {

        var valuefirstone = $(this).val();//use jquery built in functions
        alert(valuefirstone);

    });

});
```

Make sure you wrapped the change function with document ready fn

Answer (score 0):

you can easily do with below code:

```
 $("#value_date").on('change', function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   alert(this.value);
  /* Act on the event */
  });
```