# Get the value of datepicker on change in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I need to get the value of `datepicker` on `change`, But it is returning `undefined`.

**HTML :**

```
<input  id="#return" name="start" class="date-pick form-control" value="" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" type="text" />
```

**JS :**

```
$('input.date-pick').datepicker().on('changeDate', function (ev) {
      var firstDate = $('#return').val();
      alert(firstDate);
});
```

Comment: You've asked the [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38450944/how-to-get-the-value-of-date-picker-on-change-in-jquery) 5 hours earlier...

Comment: Here is an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471959/jquery-datepicker-onchange-event-help) in stackoverflow too !!!

Answer (score 5):

You could also use regular event `change` :

```
$('input.date-pick').datepicker().on('change', function (ev) {
   var firstDate = $(this).val();
   alert(firstDate);
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

Use `onSelect` event and you can get selected value with in `dateText` variable

```
$('.date-pick').datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
      alert(dateText);
    }
});
```

Comment: @KirankumarDafda The inst parameter is an internal object that captures the current state of the datepicker. Normally you don't need to use it at all. Inside the callback

Answer (score 3):

you can easily do with below code:

```
 $(".date-pick").on('change', function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   alert(this.value);
  /* Act on the event */
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your date field

```
<input id="thedate" type="text" class="date-pick"/>
```

And if you using bootstrap datepicker then add this script code

```
$(function() {

  $('.date-pick').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
      alert(dateText);
    }
  });

});
```

Here is the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/s1L5pjpb/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the value directly from your `onchange` event:

```
onChange="variable=$(this).val();"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#datepickerID").on('change', function() {
  dateVar = $("this").val();
}
```

You can get value by calling function when `onchange` event occur. Then, after you can store that value, alert it or print it on console.